# Pine script, multiple errors when trying to migrate indicator from version 2 to 4

Tags: pine-script

I was wondering if anyone could help me migrate an indicator called "Well Rounded Moving Average" from v2 to v4. It's the middle part that needs to be changed by adding the var fonction (I'm guessing) but I have no knowledge of coding and I'm learning as I go.
I tried a few things but at best I get two errors stating "Undeclared identifier" for 'A' and 'B' when adding var for 'a' and 'b'. Obviously color=red is now color=color.red.

And here's the link to the indicator on TV: https://www.tradingview.com/script/Ez0QYKPI-Well-Rounded-Moving-Average/

If anyone could help it'd be awesome! Thanks!

```
//@version=2

study("Well Rounded Moving Average",shorttitle="WRMA",overlay=true)

length = input(14),src = input(close),smo = input(false, title="Extra Smooth")

//----

alpha = 2/(length+1)

p1 = smo ? length/4 : 1

p2 = smo ? length/4 : length/2

//----

a = nz(a[1]) + alpha*nz(A[1])

b = nz(b[1]) + alpha*nz(B[1])

y = ema(a + b,p1)

A = src - y

B = src - ema(y,p2)

//----

plot(y,color=red,transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4

study("Well Rounded Moving Average",shorttitle="WRMA",overlay=true)

length = input(14),src = input(close),smo = input(false, title="Extra Smooth")

//----

alpha = 2/(length+1)

p1 = smo ? length/4 : 1

p2 = smo ? length/4 : length/2

//----
var float a = na
var float b = na
var float A = na
var float B = na
a := nz(a[1]) + alpha*nz(A[1])

b := nz(b[1]) + alpha*nz(B[1])

y = ema(a + b,p1)

A := src - y

B := src - ema(y,p2)

//----

plot(y,color=color.red,transp=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I did have to add ':' for the a, b, A, and B equations as well and now it all works!